# Using dot-env for my MongoDB username / password

Tags: mongodb, dotenv

I've coded a blog website which is now fully functioning but I can't figure out how to use dot-env for the username / password which needs to go into the MongoDB connection request in my server.js file.

For example, I'm using Mongoose to connect like so:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@jons-thoughts.xpo8p.mongodb.net/jons-thoughts?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
```

The database works great when I put the username / password in as plain text. However... If I replace them with dot-env variables, like so:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://process.env.MONGO_USERNAME:process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD@jons-thoughts.xpo8p.mongodb.net/jons-thoughts?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
```

It doesn't work - I get an error in my terminal (currently hosting it on localhost) stating authentication failed.

Is there a way around this? How would I do it if so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually passing the string `"process.env.MONGO_USERNAME"` and `"process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD"` as username and password.

You will have to get the variables` value instead.

There are several ways, for example

1. Use ES2015 [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@jons-thoughts.xpo8p.mongodb.net/jons-thoughts?retryWrites=true&w=majority`);
```

2. Use string concatenation

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://' + process.env.MONGO_USERNAME + ':' + process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD + '@jons-thoughts.xpo8p.mongodb.net/jons-thoughts?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
```

TIP: You can also put the whole connection string in an environment variable

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@jons-thoughts.xpo8p.mongodb.net/jons-thoughts?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
```